# Memory allocation problem Google Cloud Run

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-run, alpine-linux

I have a Python3.9 application running in a Docker environment through Google Run. For several weeks this has built and run without error.

However, starting on Friday 11th November 2022, a runtime memory allocation error began to arise when I hit REST API endpoints with single requests:

```
Memory limit of 256M exceeded with 256M used. Consider increasing the memory limit
```

I did not change our code at all between the time that there was no error and the error showing.

And, indeed, I can resolve the error by increasing the memory limit to 512MB, but I am concerned by the fact that the system is built with Python3.9 on Alpine, with what should be little more than 130MB-150MB of memory. Indeed, the Google Run logs show that, prior to 11th November, memory was running at 50% (of 250MB), roughly in accordance with what we would expect from the Alpine installation.

Has anyone else seen this kind of recent memory allocation error arising since the 10th or 11th November 2020? And, if so, how did you fix it and what was causing the root cause?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

For reference, the Dockerfile I am using is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.16

ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT true
ENV PIPENV_NOSPIN true

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . $APP_HOME
COPY xiglogger $APP_HOME

RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssh git
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN  pip install pipenv  \
    && pipenv requirements > requirements.txt \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PORT 8080

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED TRUE

CMD pipenv run gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

Comment: It can be pretty everything since nothing in your build is stable. You're using docker tag that is permanently new built, you're fetching newest dependencies with apt get and pip install, and your code most likely also change.

Comment: There could be many reasons. You will need to figure out your application's memory requirements and why it exceeded 256 MB (normal or not normal). As written, we can only guess what the actual problem is.

Comment: Did you build and deploy a new container in the week leading up to Nov 11? If not, I would assume that the data processed by your container has changed. That has happened to me. My Cloud Run service started working on larger picture files which caused it to run out of memory.

Comment: Have you checked above suggestions?